# Error in instantiating a java class in a file in a package

Tags: java, package

I have the following directory structure -

```
test2
I_ bioData.java
I_ progTest.java
```

Here are the contents of bioData.java -

```
class bioData
{
    String name;
    int age;

    bioData(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    void showData()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nAge: " + age);
    }
}
```

The contents of progTest.java are -

```
class progTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        bioData a = new bioData("Sam", 15);
        a.showData();
    }
}
```

I used the following lines to compile these files ( Note: I am compiling from inside the test2 folder and am using JDK 15)-

```
>javac bioData.java
>javac progTest.java
```

All goes well till now. But, then, I want to convert them into package. So, I include

```
package test2;
```

on the top of bioData.java file, resulting in following code -

```
package test2;

class bioData
{
    String name;
    int age;

    bioData(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    void showData()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nAge: " + age);
    }
}
```

It compiles well but, progTest.java fails to compile, stating that it is unable to find the bioData class.

WHAT I DID TO RESOLVE MY ISSUE -
I included this package test2; statement on top of progTest.java file, but, even then, it fails! I tried importing the bioData file in progTest.java too, but, it also failed.

Comment: It's unclear what changed after you added package declarations. Please add the content of the files. Also, please indicate *how you're building in both cases (where are you calling `javac` from?)*

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question accordingly.